# UWP: Invalid Binding Path : Property not found on type DataTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, binding

I'm building my first **UWP** application, i've been with WPF for some time,
I'm trying to bind a **Listview itemsSource** but i keep getting the next error:

- Invalid binding path 'Fletes' : Property 'Fletes' not found on type 'DataTemplate'.

I've tried

```
 <ListView ItemsSource ={Binding Viewmodel.Fletes}/>
```

in xaml, removing `x:DataType`

and
using `this.DataContext = ViewModel` on .cs

Here's my code:

**Views/HomeFletes.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Internal.Views
{
    public sealed partial class HomeFletes : Page
    {
        public FletesViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public HomeFletes()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new FletesViewModel();
        }


        private void MasterDetailsView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("loaded");
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/HomeFletes.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Internal.Views.HomeFletes"
    xmlns:local="using:Internal"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="using:Internal.Models"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView
        Loaded="MasterDetailsView_Loaded"
        CompactModeThresholdWidth="720">
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Fletes}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="model:Flete">
                            <RelativePanel Margin="24">
                                <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="OrangeRed">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Transporte}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Comentario}" x:Phase="2"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                               
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
</Page>
```

**/ViewModels/FletesViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Internal.ViewModels
{
    public class FletesViewModel : BindableBase
    { 
        private ObservableCollection<Flete> fletes = new ObservableCollection<Flete>();
        public ObservableCollection<Flete> Fletes { get { return this.fletes; } }

        public FletesViewModel()
        {
            this.fletes.Add(new Flete() { Transporte = "Transporte #1", Fecha = DateTime.Now, Comentario = "Este es el comentario #1" });
            this.fletes.Add(new Flete() { Transporte = "Transporte #2", Fecha = DateTime.Now, Comentario = "Este es el comentario #2" });
            this.fletes.Add(new Flete() { Transporte = "Transporte #3", Fecha = DateTime.Now, Comentario = "Este es el comentario #3" });
            this.fletes.Add(new Flete() { Transporte = "Transporte #4", Fecha = DateTime.Now, Comentario = "Este es el comentario #4" });
        }


    }
}
```

**/Models/Flete.cs**

```
    namespace Internal.Models
{
    public class Flete : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Transporte { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: xmlns:model="using:Internal.Models"   here look for your models path

Comment: But that's the right path to Models Namespace. I'm so lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Invalid binding path 'Fletes' : Property 'Fletes' not found on type 'DataTemplate'.

Inside a DataTemplate, the value of Path is not interpreted in the context of the page, but in the context of the data object being templated. The data the ListView inside the DataTemplate can bind with depends on the the ItemsSource of MasterDetailsView, you didn't set the ItemsSource for the MasterDetailsView, the ListView can not bind correctly.

In addition, the MasterDetailsView Control presents items in a master/details pattern. It shows a collection of items within the "master panel", so you do not need to declare a ListView in it, the "master panel" works as ListView, you can set the ItemsSource for MasterDetailsView directly. For exmaple:

HomeFletes.xaml

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView x:Name="MyDetailsView"
        Loaded="MasterDetailsView_Loaded"
        CompactModeThresholdWidth="720" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Fletes}">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Flete">
            <RelativePanel Margin="24">
                <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="OrangeRed">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Transporte}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Comentario}" x:Phase="2"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i wanted to do! I was focused on making my ListView work that i couldn't see the whole picture.